# Getting specific number on specific episode for patients

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, group-by, where-clause

I am trying to get the most recent axis_I_II_3 number for each patient. I need a way to get the latest date on the highest episode number for each patient_id. Was hoping someone could help me with this.

```
select

distinct pct.patient_id,
pct.episode_id,
pct.axis_I_II_3,
pct.proc_chron,
pct.clinic_id

from patient_clin_tran pct
join patient p on pct.patient_id = p.patient_id
where pct.axis_I_II_3 is not null and p.case_status = 'A' and pct.patient_id not in ('00000004')
```

[image]

Comment: you haven't mentioned the platform - from the screen shot looks like SQL Server, but what version?

Comment: SQL Server 2005. Thanks.

Comment: @JeremyMcDevitt: I have added the tag for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of construct will give you the answer.

```
select  pct.patient_id,
pct.episode_id,
pct.axis_I_II_3,
pct.proc_chron,
pct.clinic_id

from patient_clin_tran pct
join patient p on pct.patient_id = p.patient_id
join (
select patient_id, max(proc_chron) maxdate
from patient_clin_tran
where whatever
group by patient_id
) temp on temp.patient_id = pct.patient_id and pct.proc_chron = maxdate
etc
```

You can add the where clauses and fix any syntax errors I might have made.

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "pct.axis_I_II_3" could not be bound.

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "p.case_status" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "pct.patient_id" could not be bound.